# Invert the channels of a stereo audio file within a mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a mp4 that contains a stereo audio file whose channels are inverted, right is left, left is right. How do I invert the stereo audio file within the mp4 with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#Switchstereochannels does contain a couple of simple advice, though it is only demonstrated on audio files:

Either

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.ogg -map_channel 0.0.1 -map_channel 0.0.0 output.wav
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.ogg -af pan=stereo|c0=c1|c1=c0 output.wav
```

With mere ffmpeg, chances are this cannot be done without re-encoding, such manipulations often require more specialized tools (like mp3directCut, in case of mp3, and so on).

Comment: While the audio must be re-encoded, the video doesn't have to be.  Use `-vcodec copy`.

Comment: If you want to avoid any encoding you can use the pan filter with a player: `ffplay -af "pan=stereo|c0=c1|c1=c0" input.mp4` or you can do it with mpv as well.

Comment: would a `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i video.mp4 -map 0:0 - map 0:1 -c:v copy -map_channel 0.0.1 -map_channel 0.0.0 videoout.mp4` work or how to make this work?

Comment: @AureliusSchnitzler Are `video.mp4` and `video.mp4` the same file, or are they supposed to represent two different files?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The same.

Comment: @AureliusSchnitzler `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "pan=stereo|c0=c1|c1=c0[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy output.mp4`